# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vafer/jdeb/Console when starting intellij sbt project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, noclassdeffounderror

Whenever I create a new simple project in Intellij, I always get stuck at this stage when the project loads the build.sbt file.

Here's the error:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /home/giangvdq/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar

**[info]** welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Private Build Java 1.8.0_265)

**[error]** java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vafer/jdeb/Console

**[error]** Use 'last' for the full log.

[Here's the build error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwbPd.png)

Here's the full log file:

```
giangvdq@L0109-GiangVDQ:~/workspaces/fpt/untitled$ sbt compile
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Ubuntu Java 11.0.8)
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vafer/jdeb/Console
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? r
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Ubuntu Java 11.0.8)
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vafer/jdeb/Console
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? last
[debug] > Exec(reload, None, None)
[debug] > Exec(sbtStashOnFailure, None, None)
[debug] > Exec(onFailure loadFailed, None, None)
[debug] > Exec(loadp, None, None)
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Ubuntu Java 11.0.8)
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vafer/jdeb/Console
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:24)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getCheckedObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:32)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1(ModuleUtilities.scala:37)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.$anonfun$map$1(Stream.scala:418)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1171)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1161)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.loop$1(Growable.scala:57)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:61)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:184)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:47)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$plus$plus(TraversableLike.scala:151)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$plus$plus$(TraversableLike.scala:147)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.$plus$plus(List.scala:210)
[error]         at sbt.internal.PluginDiscovery$.discoverAll(PluginDiscovery.scala:57)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:1299)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:1244)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.noPlugins(Load.scala:1219)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:1204)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$2(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:682)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:480)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:180)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:245)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:542)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:558)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:488)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:467)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:243)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:243)
[error]         at sbt.internal.GlobalPlugin$.build(GlobalPlugin.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.internal.GlobalPlugin$.load(GlobalPlugin.scala:64)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadGlobal(Load.scala:185)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultWithGlobal(Load.scala:143)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:50)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:46)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:847)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:847)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:801)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:144)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:187)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.process$1(MainLoop.scala:199)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:235)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:147)
[error]         at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.runCmd$1(State.scala:273)
[error]         at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.process$extension(State.scala:277)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:147)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:147)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:138)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:116)
[error]         at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:27)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:65)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:50)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:41)
[error]         at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:132)
[error]         at sbt.xMain$.run(Main.scala:67)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error]         at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.scala:45)
[error]         at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:39)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.vafer.jdeb.Console
[error]         at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:24)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getCheckedObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:32)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1(ModuleUtilities.scala:37)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.$anonfun$map$1(Stream.scala:418)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1171)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1161)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.loop$1(Growable.scala:57)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:61)
[error]         at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:184)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:47)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$plus$plus(TraversableLike.scala:151)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$plus$plus$(TraversableLike.scala:147)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.$plus$plus(List.scala:210)
[error]         at sbt.internal.PluginDiscovery$.discoverAll(PluginDiscovery.scala:57)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:1299)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:1244)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.noPlugins(Load.scala:1219)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:1204)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$2(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:682)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:480)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:180)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:245)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:542)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:558)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:488)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:467)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:243)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:243)
[error]         at sbt.internal.GlobalPlugin$.build(GlobalPlugin.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.internal.GlobalPlugin$.load(GlobalPlugin.scala:64)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadGlobal(Load.scala:185)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultWithGlobal(Load.scala:143)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:50)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:46)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:847)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:847)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:801)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:144)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:187)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.process$1(MainLoop.scala:199)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:235)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:147)
[error]         at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.runCmd$1(State.scala:273)
[error]         at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.process$extension(State.scala:277)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:147)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:147)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:138)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:116)
[error]         at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:27)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:65)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:50)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:41)
[error]         at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:132)
[error]         at sbt.xMain$.run(Main.scala:67)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error]         at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.scala:45)
[error]         at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:39)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vafer/jdeb/Console
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[debug] > Exec(loadFailed, None, None)
[debug] > Exec(last, None, None)
```

Before this I might have copied some .jar files from one project to another and this issue arose from then.
I've tried resetting Intellij to defaults, when that didn't work, I tried removing the Intellij installation and its related folders, excluding .ivy and .sbt folders. But nothing worked. I didn't try to delete any jar files though because I didn't wanna mess it up further.

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you try the suggestions at: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/1053 ?

Comment: @TomerShetah I did, it didn't work but I solved the issue, posted below. But thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found the solution.

I went into this directory /home/username/ and deleted the .sbt folder.
I also reinstalled Intellij and everything worked again